# How to install Ubuntu Touch on an iphone 4?

Tags: ubuntu, iphone

Is it possible to install Ubuntu Touch on an iPhone 4? In my research, some claimed it wasn't, but I'm not convinced. I found some tutorials for the Nexus phone, and a [forum thread](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/218183), but it wasn't very clear.

How can it be done? Does it require an Ubuntu desktop? The iPhone I'm installing on isn't important, so I'm willing to try unsafe installations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's essentially impossible because Apple's [A Series SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_mobile_application_processors#.22Ax.22_series) used in the iPhone is way different than the generic [ARM architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch#Hardware_requirements) for which Ubuntu Touch is targeted.